# Implementing pointInpolygon search algorithm on Bing Maps with location's coordinate coming from database

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I wish to determine if a given point(latitude and longitude) is found within a drawn polygon on a Bing map or not. The polygon is drawn by the user.

This is what I already have

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var map, drawingManager;

    function GetMap() {
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {});

        //Load the DrawingTools module
        Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.DrawingTools', function () {
            //Create an instance of the DrawingTools class and bind it to the map.
            var tools = new Microsoft.Maps.DrawingTools(map);
            //Show the drawing toolbar and enable editing on the map.
            tools.showDrawingManager(function (manager) {
                //Store a reference to the drawing manager as it will be useful later.
                drawingManager = manager;
                //Create a shortcut to the DrawingBarAction to minimize code.
                var da = Microsoft.Maps.DrawingTools.DrawingBarAction;
                //Limit which tools appear in the drawing toolbar.
                manager.setOptions({
                    drawingBarActions: da.polyline | da.polygon | da.erase,
                    fillColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)'
                });
            });
        });
    }


    function IsPointInPolygon() {
        var shapes = drawingManager.getPrimitives();
        if (shapes && shapes.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
                var points = shapes[i].getLocations();

                //Get all locations from DB
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:53851/Locations/ReturnLocationsList',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {
                        //do something with data
                        //alert(JSON.stringify(response.data));
                        arrayLocations = response.data;
                        //alert(arrayLocations.length);
                        var columns = ['IdLocation', 'Name', 'Latitude', 'Longitude'];

                        //Convert gotten locations to Maps.Locations in order to ease calculations
                        var allLocations = [];
                        alert("are you here ?");

                        for (i = 0; i < arrayLocations.length; i++) {
                            var coordinates = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(arrayLocations[i].Latitude, arrayLocations[i].Longitude);
                            allLocations.push(coordinates);
                        }
                        alert(allLocations[0]);

                        //Add pushpin to each location coming from DB
                        var pinLocation = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(origin, {
                            color: 'blue'
                        });

                        for (i = 0; i < allLocations.length; i++) {
                            map.entities.push(pinLocation);

                            if (pointInPolygon(points, allLocations[i].Latitude, allLocations[i].Longitude)) {
                                alert("Point is inside polygon");
                            }
                            else {
                                alert("Point is not found in polygon");
                            }
                        }

                        function pointInPolygon(points, lat, lng) {
                            // ray-casting algorithm based on
                            // http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html

                            var inside = false;
                            for (var i = 0, j = points.length - 1; i < points.length; j = i++) {
                                var intersect =
                                    points[i].latitude > lat != points[j].latitude > lat &&
                                    lng <
                                    ((points[j].longitude - points[i].longitude) *
                                        (lat - points[i].latitude)) /
                                    (points[j].latitude - points[i].latitude) +
                                    points[i].longitude;
                                if (intersect) inside = !inside;
                            }

                            return inside;
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        //log or alert the error
                        alert("There's an error !");
                        //alert(error);
                    }
                });
            }
            //return locations;
        } else {
            alert("No shapes in the drawing manager.");
        }
    }

</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap&key=[Bing Map key]' async defer></script>
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:950px;height:500px;"></div>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Get Shapes" onclick="IsPointInPolygon()" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The arrayLocations are locations actually coming from the database and within these locations are at least one found in the drawn polygon area, but I definitely get the "Point not found in polygon" message, for all the locations.

I even tried adding pushpins to each of the locations coming from the database, but the pushpins won't display on the map.

I'm completely lost. Please for any help!

Answer (score 1):

It appears you adapted the [Polygon Search algorithm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/cc451895(v=msdn.10)#polygon-search) from official documentation, right? If so, their implementation is appears to be buggy and is not working as expected.

Instead i would propose to utilize the following one to determine whether the point is actually inside the polygon:

```
function pointInPolygon(points, lat, lng) {
  // ray-casting algorithm based on
  // http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html
  var inside = false;
  for (var i = 0, j = points.length - 1; i < points.length; j = i++) {
    var intersect =
      points[i].latitude > lat != points[j].latitude > lat &&
      lng <
        ((points[j].longitude - points[i].longitude) *
          (lat - points[i].latitude)) /
          (points[j].latitude - points[i].latitude) +
          points[i].longitude;
    if (intersect) inside = !inside;
  }

  return inside;
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var map, drawingManager, point;

function GetMap() {
  map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map("#myMap", {});

  point = map.getCenter();
  var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(point, {
    title: "Center point"
  });
  map.entities.push(pin);

  //Load the DrawingTools module
  Microsoft.Maps.loadModule("Microsoft.Maps.DrawingTools", function() {
    //Create an instance of the DrawingTools class and bind it to the map.
    var tools = new Microsoft.Maps.DrawingTools(map);
    //Show the drawing toolbar and enable editing on the map.
    tools.showDrawingManager(function(manager) {
      //Store a reference to the drawing manager as it will be useful later.
      drawingManager = manager;
      //Create a shortcut to the DrawingBarAction to minimize code.
      var da = Microsoft.Maps.DrawingTools.DrawingBarAction;
      //Limit which tools appear in the drawing toolbar.
      manager.setOptions({
        drawingBarActions: da.polyline | da.polygon | da.erase,
        fillColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)"
      });
    });
  });
}

function getShapes() {
  var shapes = drawingManager.getPrimitives();
  if (shapes && shapes.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
      var points = shapes[i].getLocations();
      if (pointInPolygon(points, point.latitude, point.longitude)) {
        alert("Point is inside polygon");
      } else {
        alert("Point is not found in polygon");
      }
    }

    //return locations;
  } else {
    alert("No shapes in the drawing manager.");
  }
}

function pointInPolygon(points, lat, lng) {
  // ray-casting algorithm based on
  // http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html
  var inside = false;
  for (var i = 0, j = points.length - 1; i < points.length; j = i++) {
    var intersect =
      points[i].latitude > lat != points[j].latitude > lat &&
      lng <
        ((points[j].longitude - points[i].longitude) *
          (lat - points[i].latitude)) /
          (points[j].latitude - points[i].latitude) +
          points[i].longitude;
    if (intersect) inside = !inside;
  }

  return inside;
}
```

```html
<div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:640px;height:320px;"></div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Get Shapes" onclick="getShapes()" />
 <script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?key=Ap12Gwv9esg5iXgfAh5Ehlbf36MZ-O8051Sl66Zm6glGwq7PSaaKgGPpcOUEGICy&callback=GetMap"
  async
  defer
></script>
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but I still get the same result, even after editing my code to fit your snippet. I have made some adjustements to my code, I edited the question so you can see what I have actually.

Comment: Thanks @Vadim Gremyachev, this works for me perfectly. You solved a big headache!